# iterating through multiple equations

Tags: python, iteration

I have a problem simplified into the following:

Xn+1 = Xn + Yn

Yn+1= Yn + Zn

Zn+1= Zn+ Xn

I know the values of X0,Y0,Z0 to be equal to 1.
I want to tell python to find the values of X1,Y1,Z1 and then X2,Y2,Z2,...etc. Can anyone help me with that? I think I have to use a nested loop but I am not sure exactly how to go about it. Thanks!

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Please show what you have tried so far. What kind of problem do you encounter? Please be specific.

Answer (score 3):

Are we talking about something as simple as:

```
x, y, z = 1, 1, 1

for i in range(10):
    print("X{i} = {x}, Y{i} = {y}, Z{i} = {z}".format(**locals()))

    x, y, z = x + y, y + z, z + x
```

which doesn't seem right as the output is so uninteresting:

```
X0 = 1, Y0 = 1, Z0 = 1
X1 = 2, Y1 = 2, Z1 = 2
X2 = 4, Y2 = 4, Z2 = 4
X3 = 8, Y3 = 8, Z3 = 8
X4 = 16, Y4 = 16, Z4 = 16
X5 = 32, Y5 = 32, Z5 = 32
X6 = 64, Y6 = 64, Z6 = 64
X7 = 128, Y7 = 128, Z7 = 128
X8 = 256, Y8 = 256, Z8 = 256
X9 = 512, Y9 = 512, Z9 = 512
```

Answer (score 1):

Below is the sample function to achieve it:

```
def solve_equation(n):
    X = {0: 1}
    Y = {0: 1}
    Z = {0: 1}
    for i in range(n):
        print 'For n: ', i+1
        X[i+1] = X[i] + Y[i]
        Y[i+1] = Y[i] + Z[i]
        Z[i+1] = Z[i] + X[i]
        print 'X = ', X[i+1], ' Y = ', Y[i+1], ' Z = ', Z[i+1]
```

Sample run:

```
>>> solve_equation(3)
For n:  1
X =  2  Y =  2  Z =  2
For n:  2
X =  4  Y =  4  Z =  4
For n:  3
X =  8  Y =  8  Z =  8
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **recursive functions**. For a faster and better code you can consider using **yield**

```
def Cvalue(c,xyz , n):
     if n == 0 :
             res = c
     else :
           if xyz == 1:   res = Cvalue(c,1, n-1) + Cvalue(c,2, n-1)
           elif xyz == 2: res = Cvalue(c,2, n-1) + Cvalue(c,3, n-1)
           elif xyz == 3: res = Cvalue(c,3, n-1) + Cvalue(c,1, n-1)
           else:  print("Error\n")
     return res

def XYZvalues(x0, y0, z0, n):
    x = Cvalue(x0,1, n)
    y = Cvalue(y0,2, n)
    z = Cvalue(z0,3, n)
    return (x, y , z)

print(XYZvalues(1,1,1, 3))
```